# Inserting NaN value into a float column

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, floating-point, nan

I need help inserting a NaN value in a float column as 0 in SQL Server 2012.

The data I have inserted into a database is coming from an active directory and sometimes it's generated NaN values, but my database column is defined as a float because I want to get those values from database and do some calculations.

```
Dim value1 As Double 

sql = "INSERT INTO usb_compliance (Date,atc,value1,) VALUES ('" & Now.Date & "','CMB','" & value1 &"' )"
```

Comment: Something like "case when val = 'NaN' then 0.0 else val end"?

Comment: most of the time its the active directory generate numbers but when its generate NaN then my SQL code says error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First**, Never concatenate strings to create sql statements.
This is a security risk as it's an open door for [Sql injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) attacks.
Use parameterized queries instead.

Second, I would recommend using `null` to represent `NaN` values since 0.0 is a valid float value and `NaN` stands for Not A Number, and is basically an unknowable value, just like `null` in Sql server.

Having said that, you can simply use a condition in your vb.net like this:

```vb
Sub InsertValues(ByVal atc As String, ByVal value1 As Double, ByVal d As DateTime)
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO usb_compliance (Date,atc,value1) VALUES (@Date, @atc,@value1)"
    ' SqlConnection con is defined and set elsewhere
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    With cmd
        .Connection.Open()
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = d
        .Parameters.Add("@atc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = atc
        .Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.Float).Value = IIf(Double.IsNaN(value1), DBNull.Value, value1)
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
End Sub

' overload since optional parameter can't be non-constant DateTime.Now
Sub InsertValues(ByVal atc As String, ByVal value1 As Double)
    InsertValues(atc, value1, DateTime.Now)
End Sub
```

and just call it like this:

```vb
InsertValues("CMB", value1) '' To use the Now.Date
InsertValues("ERT", value1, DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)) '' to insert the date 3 days from now
```

Comment: it say the error in value1.IsNaN as IsNaN not a member of 'integer' (i have assigned the value1 as integer )
what can i do?

Comment: And now i have more values like VALUES ('" & Now.Date & "','CMB','" & value1 &"' ), ('" & Now.Date & "','ERT','" & value1 &"' ), ('" & Now.Date & "','ERT','" & value1 &"' )

Comment: how can i add this in parameterized queries??? if i add am i need to use the IFF for each values or is there any easy way (Please help me)

Comment: You can wrap it all in a function and just call it with different values each time. If it solves your problem, please accept the answer so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: can you please give an example ?

Comment: nice and i used a vb method: problem solved 
thanks again :)

Comment: "First, Never concatenate strings to create sql statements." - 
No, First, understand the rules.  "Never concatenate _unsanitized_ strings."

If, in this case, you are completely in control of the strings used, there is literally zero danger in concatenating strings.

Comment: @Marc sanitation is not a safe way to prevent SQL injection, however I do agree that if the user doesn't control the strings that get sent to the database, it's not a risk. 
That being said, using parameters wherever possible is best practice and has other advantages over concatenated strings such as type safety and execution plan caching.